# similarity comparison using sliding window over image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

original image is

[image]

I would like to compare the rectangular objects present in this image with a rectangular mask?how can i select a rectangular mask? How to compare the similarity of rectangular like image and a mask. I would like to check the similarity using
[image]
from the paper
A Fractional Fourier Transform Based Method of Image Fusion. For this,  I wrote a sliding window template. How to implement this equation :

```
I = imread('test1.png');
imageWidth = size(I, 2);
imageHeight = size(I, 1);

windowWidth = 32;
windowHeight = 32;

for j = 1:imageHeight - windowHeight + 1
    for i = 1:imageWidth - windowWidth + 1
        window = I(j:j + windowHeight - 1, i:i + windowWidth - 1, :);
        S(j,i)=sum(sum(abs(window).*abs(mask)))/(sum(sum(window.^2))+sum(sum(mask.^2)));
    end
end
```

Comment: The parameters in the equation such as `K`,`L`, and `f` are not defined.

Comment: f is the image,K and L are the height and width of image

Comment: Are K and L the size of the entire image or the mask?

Comment: It is either or, yes does not make sense here. Given what you are doing I assume you mean the mask.

Answer (score 1):

Having extracted your window if I understand your similarity function correctly then

```
S(j, i)=sum(sum(abs(window).*abs(mask)))/(sum(sum(window.^2))+sum(sum(mask.^2)));
```

For efficiency it would probably be better to use [nlfilter](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html) to perform a sliding window operation on your image.

First you need to create a function to calculate the similarity. The simplest way is to do this as an anonymous function of the form:

```
similarity=@(M) 'Implent your similarity function here..';
```

As mask doesn't change when you silde your window you should be able to just call it directly and not need it as a variable of your function.

Then call `nlfilter(img, [m n], similarity);` where [m n] gives the size of the window you want to use.

Comment: i didnt understand.i dont know anonymous function.can you rearrange it

Comment: The bit for the anonymous function is same thing as in the RHS of S(j,i)=... with window replaced by M (or change M to window)